# FirebaseAnalytics: logging events to multiple projects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I need to send FirebaseAnalytics events to two separate accounts. I've tried working with pure GAI but it is not showing in Firebase console.

How could I do that?

Comment: This is a bit vague - what does *two separate accounts* mean?

Comment: @Jay, yes. Two separate accounts.

Comment: If you can answer my question (instead of saying it again) we may be able to help.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean there're two projects at my firebase console. I want to send events to both of them.

Comment: For the future generations: we've decided to send other-hand statistics to the google analytics. Why two analytics systems? It was a business requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question.

Judging by the documentation and heavy personal research: there is no legal (or without the black magic) way to split analytics data into two separate Firebase projects.

[Quote](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application):

> Note: On Android and iOS, Analytics are only logged for the default app
>   And switching default app on the fly didn't work.

Therefore, our team has decided to acquire google analytics account as a second analytics channel which solves our needs.

Hope it will help someone.

P.S. If you need to split debug data from release data watch Martin's answer.

Answer (score 3):

[here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) it is covered for Android, while on the Firebase console, it is exactly the same:

however, it might be better (unless the goal is to tell apart debug & release builds),

to tell apart by the [CAMPAIGN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Param.html#CAMPAIGN) and/or [CAMPAIGN_DETAILS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#CAMPAIGN_DETAILS).

as the Firebase documentation for [Reliable Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#reliable-analytics) states:

> If runtime configuration is required, please note the following caveats:
>
> If you're using AdMob and request ads at startup as recommended, you may miss some Analytics data to related to mobile ads when not using the resource based configuration approach.
>
> Only ever supply a single Google app ID in each distributed variant of your app. For example, if you ship version 1 of your app with a certain `GOOGLE_APP_ID` in the configuration then upload version 2 with a different ID, it may cause analytics data to be dropped.
>
> On `iOS`, do not add `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project if you are supplying different configuration at run time, as this can result in an apparent change of `GOOGLE_APP_ID` and result in lost Analytics.

also see [Manage project members](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en) ...in order to grant access to another Google account.

telling apart by campaigns makes sense, because alike that one can have several campaigns, while being able to compare their performance - which one otherwise could not, at least not that directly.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I don't see there an option to log events simultaneously to two different projects. The links you sent are telling about two separate accounts which usages depends on project's configuration. Maybe I miss something, could you point the exact place where it is mentioned?

Comment: I have projects set up exactly as it is explained on the first one link (my purpose is to tell apart debug and release crashes) - while your question is rather vague, not really permitting to understand the purpose of it ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to first configure two different apps in your project. Then you can log separately to each one of them.

More info here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/#support_multiple_environments_in_your_ios_application

Comment: "Note: On Android and iOS, Analytics are only logged for the default app." doesn't seem that easy

Comment: @Mehdzor I think that applies to default events. Can you clarify if you need all default events going to two separate projects or is your goal to log custom events to different places based on the event. I think the root problem you are trying to solve will change the solution.

Comment: That documentation page says nothing about logging events. You use the `FIRAnalytics` singleton to log events, and there's no obvious way there to differentiate between separate Firebase projects there.